# How can I get a file when I know the partial name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filenames

I need to `getJSON` a file in jQuery, but I don't know the full filename, because it's uploaded by a 3rd party that adds a random string to the URL.
`*lessons.json*` is renamed to `*lessons[123456789].json*`
Is there a way I can find that file and get it with `getJSON`?

Comment: If you are not afraid of getting blocked you can brute force it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the server you are requesting the JSON from also provides another service that tells you what URLs are available: No.